# Using icewm with vnc4server on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, vncserver

I have a strange problem with my vncserver install using icewm -- none of the XPM files for the themes load when vncserver is launched via init.d scripts.

In my `/etc/init.d/vncserver` file, it runs the equivalent of:

```
su jessica -c "/usr/bin/vncserver -name vnc-server -depth 32 -geometry 1024x768 :0"
```

And in my `~/.vnc/xstartup` file:

```
[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid black
vncconfig -iconic &
icewm-session &
```

If I run vncserver from my user account directly, everything behaves properly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was specifying a depth of 32. Changing it to 24 allowed the XPMs to load... =/

Answer (score 1):

If you use `su - <username>` it sets the $PATH variable and all the other environment variables to the same as the user's login shell.

Try:

```
su - jessica -c "/usr/bin/vncserver -name vnc-server -depth 32 -geometry 1024x768 :0"
```

and see if it works. Why are you starting a vncserver on screen :0 instead of the default :1?

Comment: It's a completely headless server; means I don't have to add the :1 when connecting.